# Want to darken a font just a little

Tags: luatex, fontspec

I see where my description may have been misleading, so here is a revised question. I want to make "dog" just a little darkder than the normal text. I do not want it to be anywhere near as dark as "fox." I am using fontspec with lualatex.

I'm trying to match the italics of a font to another that's just slightly darker. Is there a way I can do that with FakeBold? In the example below, "dog" is just as dark as "fox," but I only want to darken it a little bit.

(Using GentiumPlus here just as an example. It's not my actual font.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{GentiumPlus}

\newfontfamily{\fbgentium}{GentiumPlus}[%
  ItalicFeatures={FakeBold=1.5},
  Scale = MatchLowercase]

% Want this to be just slightly dark
\newfontfamily{\ltgentium}{GentiumPlus}[%
  ItalicFeatures={FakeBold=1.05}, % specify a small amount here (tried 0.05)
  Scale = MatchLowercase]

\begin{document}
\itshape
The quick brown {\fbgentium fox}
jumps over the lazy {\ltgentium dog.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I removed an earlier comment, after reviewing the code more. Did you really use FakeBold=.05, or did you mean 1.05 ? That should work. You may also combine it with FakeStretch if horizontal and vertical adjustments are not the same, with is quite common for serif fonts (especially if italic).

Comment: No, dog is lighter than fox. Replace the word dog by fox (in order to you can compare the same words) and start a new paragraph (empty line) before "jumps" (in order you get the tests close to each other. Then zoom the result. You can see a difference.

Comment: I can't see the difference, but it doesn't matter. I want "dog" to be slightly darker than the regular text, and nowhere near as dark as it is. I've edited the question in hopes of being more clear.

Comment: An authoritative TeX and font master, Khaled Hosny, responded to this at GitHub. It seems that `fontspec` does write different code in the PDF for each value. But it is up to the PDF reader to decide what to do about that. Apparently, some (maybe all) readers decide to display little or no difference. So it is not a problem involving `fontspec`. Issue closed at GitHub.

Comment: So this is apparently implemented via a PDF feature that is at best unreliably implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just submitted issue #498 to the GitHub page for latex3/fontspec. Linked to this thread at SE. When they get back to me, I will comment here. Meanwhile, work-around (works with lualatex):

In most cases, especially for text at normal or near-normal size, the visual appearance of weight is more closely related to the vertical stems, than to the horizontal stems. This is because most characters have thicker vertical stems.

The `fontspec` setting for `FakeStretch` works well. All it does is horizontally scale, which is a simple linear transform, and is about as bug-free as possible. So, for a small weight change, I would use `FakeStretch` for now, and wait for a resolution on `FakeBold`.

If you must also change the weight of horizontal stems, that cannot be done by `FakeStretch`. But if necessary, you could increase the size of the font using `ScaleAgain` and compensate with the `FakeStretch` value.

Related note: I use a combination of `ScaleAgain` and `FakeStretch` to create synthetic small caps, for fonts that do not have them. Not perfect, but good.

Comment: Thanks, link is this: https://github.com/latex3/fontspec/issues/498

Comment: I'll play around with this. The font I'm trying to darken is conveniently a little too condensed to match my main font as well, so this may just work out...

Answer (score 6):

Both TeX engines [XeTeX] and [LuaTeX with luaotfload] support the engine-implemented font feature `embolden=decimal_number` for OpenType fonts. PDF standard defines two basic painting routines for closed curves: `fill` and `stroke`. The `fill` routine inserts the ink only inside the closed curve and stroke draws the curve with a line, its width must be declared. The painting of letters of fonts are done only by `fill` routine by default. When the engine-dependent font feature `embolden=decimal number` is set then the letters of the used font are painted by both routines: `fill` plus `stroke` and the line width of the `stroke` routine is set to `decimal_number/100 em`.

For example, you can try using using `xetex`:

```
\font\fa=[lmroman10-regular]
\font\fb=[lmroman10-regular]:embolden=1.7

\fa Default: only fill is used.

\fb Special: fill plus stroke is used.

\bye
```

The LaTeX fontspec package converts its specific syntax `FakeBold=decimal number` to the `embolden=decimal_number` font feature internally.

I add the following image for greater clarity, how fill and stroke routines work:

[image: fill and stroke]

Comment: I get the same results with FakeBold=1.001 as I do with FakeBold=1.5

Comment: I get different results with `embolden=1.001` and `embolden=1.5`.  And I am not using LaTeX, so I din't use `fontspec`.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand the syntax in your answer. I'm using fontspec with lualatex.

Comment: @dedded You are correct! I just performed a test document (using my own document, compiled with lualatex). `FakeBold=1.05` and `FakeBold=1.5` do produce the same results, at least when used with Latin Modern Roman. This is unexpected. The 1.05 should be slightly darker. Possible `fontspec` bug? I do not recall seeing that in the past.